# Force 'show more/show less' to disable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've inherited a SaaS/web based 'design online' website, and it runs okay for our small business, before I have plans for a full Magento2 build, however there is a 'show more/show less' function I would like to get rid of on the product pages. See here, for example:

https://black-rhodium.co.uk/Products#!/products/allegro-s

I can drop blocks of code in, but don't have an option in the back end of the web based site builder to turn this 'see more/see less' feature on and off.

Can any of you guys help me with a snippet of code to force it to disappear, so I just have the block of text for the product to display as normal?

I have a sneaking suspicion it may be this part?

```
<div class="ws-clamp-text-show-hide focus">Show more</div>
```

Many thanks

> > > edit solved, many thanks :)

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted and vote it if it helped you, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.ws-clamp-text-show-hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Looks like the **Show more** div has already `ws-clamp-text-show-hide` css class. In this case, and being sure that no other element you want to keep visible, you can simply do:

```
.ws-clamp-text-show-hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: does this need to go into <body> or <body2> ?

Comment: I've dropped this in, but to no avail. 
    <divclass=".ws-clamp-text-show-hide {
    display: none;"

Comment: There are plenty of HTML and CSS tutorials in the web, please dedicate some time to learn the basics of both. Shortly, the code I suggested should go into a `<css>` block, or even better - into a `.css` file which is included by your `html` file.

Comment: Hi Guyaloni, have done this, and in blocks, to no avail. 
<html>
<css>
<divclass="ws-clamp-text-show-hide focus"</div>
</divclass>
</css>
</html>

Comment: Sorry @AlexanderBeswick, but according to your comments you miss the basics. You can have a look at theses basic [html](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) and [css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) tutorials for example. Your css syntax is wrong, also your div coding (there must be a space between the tag name, in this case `div`, and its attributes, in this example `class`).

Comment: Please mark answer as accepted and vote it if it helped you, thanks!